# How to pass props data in google-map-react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am making a small map application, using google-maps-react
below is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    const style = {
      width: '50%',
      height: '50%'
    }
    const latUse = this.props.userdata[id - 1].address.geo.lat;
    const lngUse = this.props.userdata[id - 1].address.geo.lng;
    return(
      <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          style={style}
          initialCenter={{
            lat: 35.574138,
            lng: 85.088848
          }}
          zoom={15}
          onClick={this.onMapClicked}
        />
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "...MYAPIKEY..."
})(App)
```

As you can see that I have given coordinates of `lat` and `lng`. But instead of directly writing the coordinates I want to add `latUse` and `lngUse`, in which I am getting the coordinates through my props.

I am very new to react, and I am not getting any idea on how to do it. I just want replace the hard coded coordinates of `lat` and `lng` with `latUse` and `lngUse`

Comment: sorry but not sure what you meant... why don't you try to write like this?
initialCenter={{lat: latUse, lng: lngUse}}

Comment: You can indeed directly put the latUse and lngUse as value of your initialCenter lat lng as answered above by web-sudo.Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-ktkbvv?file=Map.js) Please remove your API key from your question and please don't share these in public sites.